# Programmatically added view objects not showing up in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-storyboard

I can't see any of the view objects I've added programmatically. I need to link them to `IBAction` and/or `IBOutlet`, but without being able to `ctrl-click-drag`, I can't.

For example, I have this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(789, 60, 215, 72)];
[imageView setAnimationImages:imgListArray];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

The animation shows up in the simulator, but not in the storyboard.

How can I either make these objects show up in storyboard (preferred), or link them to `IBActions/Outlets` programmatically?

Comment: storyboard aren't something like an iterative environment. The yelp you to set up view hierarchies and transitions between view controllers, you they won't never show what you add pro grammatical.

Comment: I see...I was taking the completely wrong approach. I've got it figured out. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As @vikingsegundo said, Image Builder allows you to add objects to views and then connect them to IBOutlets and IBActions in your classes, but if you add things programatically then you are on your own in terms of Image Builder/Storyboards.

You can still create an iVar or property (preferred) to store the reference to your object, but you don't need the IBOutlet tag, so

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
```

and then

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(789, 60, 215, 72)];
[self.imageView setAnimationImages:imgListArray];
[self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
```

You can also add action handlers to objects through code (the equivalent of ctrl-dragging to an IBAction method)

```
[self.aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEventHandler) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a code-instantiated object as an instance variable, just set it. Like this:

```
// your code 
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(789, 60, 215, 72)];
[imageView setAnimationImages:imgListArray];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
// and then:
self.myImageView = imageView; // assumes you've got a `@property` called `myImageView`
```

That's exactly the same thing that constructing an outlet connection in the storyboard does, but now you're doing it yourself.

To set a code-instantiated control's action, call `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`.

That's exactly the same thing that setting up an action connection in the storyboard does, but now you're doing it yourself.